# websphere session doesn't expire

Tags: websphere

I work with websphere server and I want to expire the session.

I configured in my application ear the deployment.xml file

```
<tuningParams xmi:id="TuningParams_1188878529796" 
                     usingMultiRowSchema="false" 
                     maxInMemorySessionCount="1000" 
                     allowOverflow="true" 
                     scheduleInvalidation="false" 
                     writeFrequency="TIME_BASED_WRITE" 
                     writeInterval="10" 
                     writeContents="ONLY_UPDATED_ATTRIBUTES" 
                     invalidationTimeout="4">
```

After this, the session doesn't expire.

What do I have to configure to expire the session?

Comment: This is for replicating sessions in the cluster. What is your real requirement?

Comment: I don't work with cluster. The requirement only is the session doesn't expire

Comment: Sessions by default expire after 30 minutes of inactivity. You dont have to configure anything else. If you want to customize that you can do it either globally via admin console or via `web.xml` adding `<session-config> 
<session-timeout><timeout_value_in_minutes></session-timeout> 
</session-config>`.

Comment: I tried to configure in the admin console. I changed the session's time of the server. But the application and module configuration are disable.

Comment: Here is documentation [Configuring session management by level](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/tprs_cnfs.html). Make sure, you checked the `Override session management`, if you are doing that on applicatoin/module level. And if you are running directly from Eclipse, make sure to configure to run with resources on the server.